# Pine script: I want to buy stock everyday at 0930 and sell 1500 Hrs

Tags: pine-script

Please help me, I am new to pine.
I want to buy stock everyday at 0930 and sell 1500 Hrs.

```
strategy("SS", overlay=true, initial_capital=500000)
if (time(period, "0920-0921:12345"))
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, strategy.equity/close)
if (time(period, "1500-1501:12345"))
    strategy.close("My Long Entry Id")
```

Above code is not working please help..

Comment: Could you please explain more in details what do you mean by "code is not working". So other members could help you. If there's an error message or log please make sure to include it. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples on how to do this, you should do a search for a more specific resolution.

```
t = time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600")
plot(na(t) ? 0 : 1)
```

That's from the docs here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html?highlight=time

Use that plot and adjust the time and days until it's working how you intended, then add the strategy portion.